# Installed transforemers but cannot be imported on Google CoLab / StableDiffusion

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am trying to run the stablediffusion example from this link: https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/stable_diffusion.ipynb#scrollTo=zTDA0fvtuOIQ

```
!pip install diffusers==0.3.0
!pip install transformers scipy ftfy
!pip install "ipywidgets>=7,<8"
!pip install transformers 

from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

from huggingface_hub import notebook_login

notebook_login()
```

I installed the required dependencies and restarted the runtime and then ran the following code:

```
import torch from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=True)
```

But It spits out the following errors:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIPFeatureExtractor' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/**init**.py)

How should I fix the problem?

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue above. I ran the example from your original post on a Colab notebook with a Tesla T4 GPU. It ran successfully, but I did not restart the runtime. Note that restarting the runtime completely will remove all changes applied to the notebook.